# Can i use docking panel in Autodesk forge for both viewers?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

[Example on Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZckJO.png)

I have two viewers to compare models. I created a docking panel for properties, and I want this panel to float in two viewers. Is it possible and who will tell you how to do it?

Comment: ok, sounds like you want a 'global' panel.  You could try creating two Forge Viewers.  Then...  add a DIV element, CSS z-index:2 and with basic custom draggable code of the element.  The DIV would be draggable over both Forge Viewers.
Would that solve it ?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The problem was solved using js panels. Forge technologies do not allow the use of a docking panel for two viewers.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options:

**Option1:**

Use the '**Autodesk.SplitScreen**' extension, which will render up to 4 regions. You load it like this..

```
loadExtension('Autodesk.SplitScreen');
```

This simple extension can set up to four cameras, and render four regions. By default, it's just two (left and right).  Here's the source code for how the core of it works, just in case you want to write your own...

https://autodeskviewer.com/viewers/latest/extensions/SplitScreen/SplitScreen.js

```
this.renderScenePart = function (scene) {


// Left
if (shouldRenderForViewport[0]) {
  this.renderer.setViewport(0, vpVertStart, vpWidth, vpHeight);
  this.context.renderScenePart.apply(this.context, arguments);
}

// Right
if (shouldRenderForViewport[1]) {
  this.renderer.setViewport(vpWidth, vpVertStart, vpWidth, vpHeight);
  this.context.renderScenePart.apply(this.context, arguments);
}

// Bottom left
if (shouldRenderForViewport[2]) {
  this.renderer.setViewport(0, 0, vpWidth, vpHeight);
  this.context.renderScenePart.apply(this.context, arguments);
}

// Bottom right
if (shouldRenderForViewport[3]) {
  this.renderer.setViewport(vpWidth, 0, vpWidth, vpHeight);
  this.context.renderScenePart.apply(this.context, arguments);
}

this.renderer.setViewport(0, 0, this.width, this.height);
this.renderer.enableViewportOnOffscreenTargets(false);
```

**Option2:**

For something more advanced, and specific to just 2D, you could also try the '**Autodesk.Viewing.PixelCompare**' extension.  Here's a blog post with much more detail and a demo...

BLOG: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/compare-two-2d-documents-using-forge-viewer

[image]

Comment: Тhese are really good options, but I need something else.
I'll try to explain in the picture.
I have a Compare Panel, but it only moves within the first Viewer, but I need to move it to the second Viewer.
Is it possible to implement technology using forge or not. We did it once, but with the help of the JS panel, but we need to do it with forge.

Answer (score 0):

ok, two more options:

**option A:**
if the second image is 'static'... why not just take a 'screenshot' and place it in the right side panel?
You can use the viewer.getScreenShot() command to retrieve a PNG blog, and paint it into the canvas.

```
// Get the full image
viewer.getScreenShot(viewer.container.clientWidth, viewer.container.clientHeight, function (blobURL) {
    screenshot.src = blobURL;
});
```

For more details on drawing images to a canvas, see here: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/screenshot-markups

**option B:**
if the two panels can be independently controlled, then perhaps try to sync the camera state, with some kind of button press (or action).

with the help of these blog articles:

- https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/map-forge-viewer-camera-back-navisworks
- [Get the Camera position and restore it in Forge Viewer for a virtual visit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50775511/get-the-camera-position-and-restore-it-in-forge-viewer-for-a-virtual-visit)

for example:

`viewer.getState();`

`viewer.restoreState();`

or restore camera position using navigation object:

```
const nav = this.navigation;
nav.getTarget();
nav.getPosition();
nav.getCameraUpVector();
```