# Forge Viewer as Extension for another viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge

We have a two forge viewers in one div. We has initialize those viewers same time and showing different models. 
Is it possible to initialize Autodesk Forge viewer as extension for another viewer and show in that viewers different models?

Answer (score 0):

There is no official extension for showing one Forge Viewer inside another, but implementing this is possible. You could reuse one of the UI components of the viewer (for example, [DockingPanel](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/UI/DockingPanel/), also explained in this [tutorial](https://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/viewer/extensions/panel)), and host the second viewer in it.

Here's how such an extension might look like:

```
class MyExtension extends Autodesk.Viewing.Extension {
    constructor(viewer, options) {
        super(viewer, options);
        this._group = null;
        this._button = null;
        this._panel = null;
    }

    load() {
        return true;
    }

    unload() {
        return true;
    }

    onToolbarCreated() {
        this._group = new Autodesk.Viewing.UI.ControlGroup('allMyAwesomeExtensionsToolbar');
        this._button = new Autodesk.Viewing.UI.Button('MyExtensionButton');
        this._button.setToolTip('My Extension Button');
        this._group.addControl(this._button);
        this._panel = new MyPanel(this.viewer, this.viewer.container, 'MyPanel', 'My Panel Title');
        this._button.onClick = (ev) => {
            this._panel.setVisible(true);
        };
        this.viewer.toolbar.addControl(this._group);
    }
}

class MyPanel extends Autodesk.Viewing.UI.DockingPanel {
    constructor(viewer, container, id, title, options) {
        super(container, id, title, options);
        this.viewer = viewer;
        this.secondViewer = null;
        this.container.style.width = '640px';
        this.container.style.height = '480px';
        this.container.style.left = '1em';
        this.container.style.top = '1em';
    }

    setVisible(show) {
        super.setVisible(show);
        if (show && !this.secondViewer) {
            this.secondViewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D(this.container);
            this.secondViewer.start();
            Autodesk.Viewing.Document.load(
                'urn:<your model urn>',
                this.onDocumentLoadSuccess.bind(this),
                this.onDocumentLoadFailure.bind(this)
            );
        }
    }

    onDocumentLoadSuccess(doc) {
        const viewables = doc.getRoot().getDefaultGeometry();
        this.secondViewer.loadDocumentNode(doc, viewables);
    }

    onDocumentLoadFailure(viewerErrorCode) {
        console.error('onDocumentLoadFailure() - errorCode:' + viewerErrorCode);
    }
}

Autodesk.Viewing.theExtensionManager.registerExtension('MyExtension', MyExtension);
```

[image]

Comment: Ok, thank you. But its not a solution fo my problem. I have a some questions, would be wonderfull if you can answered to them.

Comment: I believe my answer does resolve the original question. Feel free to edit your question and add more details, or shoot us an email to `forge (dot) help (at) autodesk (dot) com` and we can take it from there.

Comment: You are right, in fact your answer is the solution to my question, but I realized that this is not a solution to my problem. I added another question about my problem. Please look at him.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60225809/can-i-use-docking-panel-in-autodesk-forge-for-both-viewers